# Starting external solver again after given elapsed time

Tags: matlab, if-statement, tableofcontents, elapsedtime

I am trying to restart external solver after given elapsed time (3600 sec) but I am not successful, therefore I would like to ask you for help.
Below is my code example. A problem is that first run is in operation and therefore if-else statement which would restart it is not taken in to account.

```
clc
close all 
clear all

tic 
! "C:\Program Files\external_solver.exe" -i file1.dat -o file1.out
et = toc 
if et > 3600; 
    ! "C:\Program Files\external_solver.exe" -i file1.dat -o file1.out 
end
;
```

Best regards
Michal

Comment: How long does your solver take to run? Do you want your 3600 seconds to be between the start of each run, or before the end of run 1 and the start of run 2?

Comment: Hello BillBokeey, normally it runs about  40 minutes, but sometimes it fails to start, shows error message and does not continue - what takes of course more than 40 minutes because it is paused by the error message. I set therefore max time of 3600 sec.  3600 sec should be from start of run 1, and when this time is up, a new run 2 should start (=restart of the failed run 1). It is not a pause between run 1 and 2.

Comment: And what do you do if the program fails? You restart it with the same inputs? Do you actually want to stop the execution of the first run of the program if it takes more than an hour to run?

Comment: If it fails then I click on OK button on the error message which closes the external solver (external solver shows that error message in case of failure). Then I start it again. Yes, I would like to stop it if it fails = takes more than an hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `"C:\Program Files\external_solver.exe" -i file1.dat -o file1.out` is a valid command, you can [append an Ampersand `'&'` to it](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1712955-how-to-continue-the-script-while-using-the-system-command) for your MATLAB script to continue while the other program executes.

Then, just make MATLAB wait for the amount of time you want, and kill the process in case it is still running. For example:

```
system('"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" &');
pause(10);
!taskkill -f -im chrome.exe
```

Comment: Hi BillBokeey, thank you very much! I am wondering how to specify waiting for closing of previously started .exe program. May I ask you for help?